# Binding Source doesn't work on column names with two or more words in DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindingsource

I am using BindingSource.Filter to filter data on my datagridview. I used the following code:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = datagridview1.DataSource;
bs.Filter = "columnName like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
datagridview1.DataSource = bs;
```

This code works. But when I filter data on a two-word column, the code does not work anymore. I tried putting apostrophe on those words like `'column name' like '%" + tbFilter.Text + "%'`, but this does not help. Please help me find the right code to filter data on my columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enclose column name in `[]`:

```
bs.Filter = "[column Name] like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
```

I think it's always a good idea even if your column names are one-word.