# How to filter datagridview rows between range?

Tags: c#, datagridview, filter, range, between

i have a column called copy number which contains only numbers like so:

```
copy number
 1
 33
 12
 40
 100
```

how can i get rows between **1** and **100** Range which is in this example are rows (33, 12, 40)?

my data is from mysql database and the GridView is populated like this:

```
MySqlDataAdapter a = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn)
DataTable t = new DataTable();
a.Fill(t);
dataGridView1.DataSource = t;
```

**PS**: answers in code will be much appreciated!

Comment: You left out a fair amount of information: how did the data get into the control?  Is it bound? What have you tried?

Comment: If your DGV is bound to a datasource, insert a "BindingSource" between the DGV and it's datasource, then use the "Filter" property of the BindingSource.

Comment: what will the filter string contain ... that's what i need?

Comment: I am assuming it's WinForms here you're talking about? Maybe take a look at this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171607(v=vs.110).aspx) which explains **Sorting Data in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control**. Specifically the page on the [DataGridView.Sort method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0868ft3z(v=vs.110).aspx) where it is explained with a C# example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try digging into the article ["BindingSource.Filter Property" on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Based on the information there, I'd try doing this to your code:

```
// your original starter code
MySqlDataAdapter a = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn)
DataTable t = new DataTable();
a.Fill(t);

// Create a seperate bindingsource object you can control
var bindingSource = new BindingSource();
bindingSource.DataSource = t;

// Now sort on a column
bindingSource.Filter = "[copy number] >= 1 AND [copy number] <= 100";

// Assign that bindingsource object to the dgv
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;
```

You might want to edit your column name `copy number` to something like `cn` or `copy_number`, I added brackets `[]` around it here, as that's [the way you can overcome it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29141154/1155847).

Comment: i am sorry to disappoint you but i didn't need sorting .What i need is a way to get rows based on a specific range (min, max).

Comment: my bad - read too fast.. have you looked into [BindingSource.Filter Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter(v=vs.110).aspx)? I'll try to adapt/edit my answer above.

Comment: @Joseph - forgot to mention - if you'd like to vary the number range you could use something like this: 
```bindingSource.Filter = String.Format("[copy number] >= {0} AND [copy number] <= {1}", number1, number2);``` - ofcourse where `number1` and `number2` are variables you can assign via a slider, or any other user input? Or use [string interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/dn961160.aspx) if you're using C# version + or above: ```bindingSource.Filter = $"[copy number] >= {number1} AND [copy number] <= {number2}";```

Comment: it Worked!!! Thank very much <<Yves Schelpe>>.